# Global Send Keys Issue

Tags: blueprism

I have an object which should highlight all text in a Word document and then press CTRL SHIFT F9 to remove all links. All the text highlights but the links remain afterwards?

I am global mouse clicking the page and then global sending "^+{F9}"

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue with [this configuration](https://i.imgur.com/Pxk5y1rl.png), which was able to Attach, activate the Word application's main document window, and send a Select All keystroke, followed by the CTRL-Shift-F9 keystroke you've provided in your question. Please provide the full configuration and inputs that you're leveraging. Is your application modeler set up correctly? Is your object attached to the correct application? Is the click that's occurring before these keystrokes actually occurring or clicking on the correct spot in the application?

Comment: Considering the extensive backend API provided for Microsoft Word and implemented by Blue Prism's bundled Business Object, you really should consider creating a new version of, or modifying the bundled version of, the `MS Word VBO` to achieve this same functionality in a way more robust, reliable way using VBA/C# interface.

Comment: So Stack Overflow is not allowing me to upload an image so will describe as best I can. The object attaches, activates, global mouse click centers and highlights all text fine. It then global mouse click centers and sends the cntrl shift F9 command. This appears to send correctly but no result.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know C#/VBA so can't do this option

Comment: You don't need to know how to write C#/VBA code to add the functionality to an extended version of the MS Word VBO. Blue Prism has official guidance on how to generate VBA code using Microsoft's Macro Recorder functionality and utilize it in an Extended version of the MS Excel VBO in its [Extending Capabilities of the MS Excel VBO](https://portal.blueprism.com/system/files/2017-11/Extending%20MS%20Excel%20VBO.PDF) document. These same concepts can be applied to create an extension of the MS Word VBO to perform the actions in the way you've described above.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think the Word Macro recorder works the same way?

Comment: I have Word Macro code of Selection.WholeStory Selection.Fields.Unlink I don't know how to convert this to Blueprism Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to get this to work by extending the Word VBO Object.

Code used

```
Dim d As Object = GetDocument(handle,document_name)

d.Select

With d.Fields
.Update
.Unlink
End With

d = Nothing
```